# Points in CIMPLICITY HMI

Tags: variables, points, hmisc

I have a HMI Cimplicity and I have to create new variables. I open the `Workbench` and go to the points, but I can´t do anything, I have to copy a variable and paste with different name, but I don´t know that I can´t. How can I do?

Thanks for all.

Comment: Please add more detail, code in R(i assume) or whatever - I for one have no idea, what you tried, what is wrong, what is already right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficient rights to create points, you can do it by:

1. Right-click on `Points` and select `New` (if you have `Points` selected, you can also just press `Ctrl-N`)
2. If you're trying to create new points with similar properties to an existing one, Right-click on the Point and select `Duplicate` (or `Ctrl-D`) as shown below.

[image: Duplicate Point]